# Run Peach Fuzzer (GitLab Protocol Fuzzer) with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gitlab, peach

Is it possible to run Peach Fuzzer (GitLab Protocol Fuzzer) with Python 3?

I didn't find any tutorials how to move Peach Fuzzer to Python 3.

Comment: I dont think there is an official support for Python 3, you can try the 2to3 tool

Comment: What is 2to3 tool?

Comment: a python tool to try to convert a python package written in python2 to python3